# Write/Update data SQLite database in iOS

Tags: ios, sqlite, flash-builder, database-connection

I have an application made ​​in air in Flash Builder for iOS plataform

I've compiled a version and installed it on my iPhone, the app talks to the database but it does not write/update in database. What can be the problem? Permission of the device or the path of the database?

thanks for now.

code:

```
private var dbFile : File;
private var dbPath : String = "SAG.sqlite"; //name of database

 private function setaAPP():void{       
    if(app == 'ANDROID'){           
        dbFile = new File('/mnt/sdcard/SAG/' + dbPath); // to ANDROID       
    }else if(app == 'DESKTOP'){
        //app == DESKTOP
        dbFile = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath(dbPath); // to DESKTOP               
    }else if(app == 'DEBUG'){
        //only to debug in Android          
        dbFile = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath(dbPath); // to DEBUG in device
    }else if(app == 'IOS'){
        //app == IOS        
        dbFile = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath(dbPath); // to iOS
    }           
}
```

Comment: Is this a sqlite db that you included when packaging the app?

Comment: yes, extension is .sqlite; In Android and desktop works good, just iOS i have this problem.

Comment: i see now, file exists! i add code : if(dbFile.exists) and the file exists, but problem persist...

Comment: Now i can read querys, but not insert/update/delete rows...

Comment: Correct. The app directory is not writable. If you want to be able to write to the database, you need to move the file somewhere writable.

Comment: @yclevine, please,how i make this? I can not stand it. here in my country almost nobody uses or program for iOS, I'm exhausted already working with it, but there's no way have to solve!

Comment: I see in the web, the one place writable in iphone is Documents folder, but what is the path? you know?

Comment: Use this: var docs:File = new File(File.userDirectory.nativePath + '/Documents');

Comment: @yclevine, thank you! My app worked, your help was very positive!

Comment: if I had 15 points level I will daba +1 in response, if you respond with this: "Use this: var docs: File = new File (File.userDirectory.nativePath + '/ Documents')" and explain why I March your answer as accepted!

Comment: Why my question is -2? i can´t ask more...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If the structure is the same as your ANDROID or DEBUG projects (i.e. you included the db in the root application directory when packaging), you should be able to use File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath(dbPath) just as you did in those cases.

EDIT:

The app directory is not writable, so if you want to write to the database, you will need to move the file to the Documents directory, which you can access with var docs:File = new File(File.userDirectory.nativePath + '/Documents');

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i include database file when i go sync with iTunes, but still not works.

Comment: Is the database file included in your project structure in Flash Builder? Check that the file is included when you package the app (under the Package Contents tab).

Comment: No, in the tab 'Package Contentes' when i release app don´t appears my database what i need to do?

Comment: Add the file under the 'src' folder in your project and then make sure that it is checked under the 'Package Contents' tab.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS, I'm guessing you want this:

```
dbFile = new File(dbPath);
```

Though you could probably also use this:

```
dbFile = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath(dbPath);
```

From [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html):

> In an iOS application, nonlocalized resources are located at the
>   top-level of the bundle directory, along with the application’s
>   executable file and the Info.plist file.

The storage or "documents" folder is going to be empty until you write files there at run time (also via iCloud syncing).

Comment: One friend tell me about don´t be possible create file in iPhone... Marcus, have you tried to create with this code? ( dbFile = new File(dbPath); )

Comment: @RafaelGrando, that creates a new file object, not a new file.

Comment: I don´t undertand, you have a example to me? - (I am brazilian and it is very difficult for me to express myself and understand what you say ...)

Comment: I'm tired of working with it, but I need to solve, I do not know what else I can do, the file exists, however it is not my connection or what ...

Comment: maybe be permissions on iOS? Now i can read data from querys, but not do insert/update/delete...

Comment: @RafaelGrando, oh, if you want to write to it (application bundle is read only), you'll need to copy the file to the documents folder and use that one.

Comment: Where is this folder? is in my project or the iPhone? please help me! My boss is pressuring me about it, no one here program for iOS, all use android only ...

Comment: i try find something in the web, but nothing about documents folder,I had hoped to finish today...

Comment: You know the path of documents folder? I owe move every time for there or I can leave fixed the file there?

Comment: @RafaelGrando, files you write to the documents folder stay until the user deletes the app. `File.applicationStorageDirectory` is probably the documents folder.

Comment: Thanks, i set the document folder in var path and works, thanks for your help!